# Display default values based on position of an element in an array formula

Tags: excel

I have a list of services which may or may not be listed starting at row 4:

```
+----+-------+
|    |   A   |
+----+-------+
| .. |       |
| 4  | Basic |
| 5  | Pro   |
| 6  |       |
| 7  |       |
+----+-------+
```

I have two named formulas, _Services and Services, which either outputs the service, or `---` if blank:

- _Services: `'Sheet1'!$A$4:$A$7`
- Services: `=IF(ISBLANK(_Services),"---", _Services)`

Instead of `---`, I want the formula to output `Service #` where `#` is the position of the service in the range.

I have tried `=IF(ISBLANK(_Services),"Service "&ROW(_Services), _Services)`, but this outputs the actual row number ie The service in cell A7 outputs as `Service 7`, but I want it to be `Service 4`.

I can't use MATCH as it either errors out or will return the first match and not the actual index.

I could do `=IF(ISBLANK(_Services),"Service "&ROW(_Services)-3, _Services)` but this isn't exactly dynamic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @pnuts Putting this in as a named formula: `=IF(ISBLANK(_Services),"Service "&MATCH(_Services,_Services,0)-3, _Services)`, then in a spreadsheet entering formula `=INDEX(Services, 3)` outputs #N/A.  It wouldn't work the way I wanted anyways as if it did match a blank, it would return the position of the first blank and not the actual blank I want. :(

Comment: @pnuts, btw, entering `=INDEX(Services, 2)` as a formula into a spreadsheet does actually return Pro, but with the #N/A error it's no good.

Comment: @pnuts, _Services is just a private name for use by Services rather than using the actual range.  So, if `Services` is defined as `=IF(ISBLANK(_Services),"Service "&MATCH(_Services,_Services,0)-3, _Services)` then `=INDEX(_Services, 2)` would output Pro and `=INDEX(_Services, 3)` would output #N/A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(ISBLANK(_Services),"Service "&ROW(_Services)-CELL("row",_Services)+1, _Services)
```